# Minify/uglify html page with embedded script tags in a nodejs app

Tags: javascript, node.js, minify, uglifyjs, html-minifier

I have an express app that, among other things, delivers some html code based on a single handlebars template.
It would be great for the use-case to deliver it with short latency. So I read and compile the template when the app starts and for now I simply call

```
res.send(
    compiledTemplateIframeContent({ data: iframeData })
)
```

All of that works flawlessly.

**The problem**

Now I would like to minify the html and uglify the js code. I tried with [html-minifier](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-minifier) but the embedded javascript is not uglified (renaming variables), not even minified (eg remove whitespaces). **I guess uglify-js is not called in the background because of some miss-configuration**. I can't find my mistake by reading the docs.

I wrote some test html code and tried it in [this online tool](https://kangax.github.io/html-minifier/). It is just a simple gui infront of html-minifier and therefor potentially a good way to test my problem.
In the online version I can at least make it compress the javascript code when I add `type="text/javascript"` to the  tag and `text/javascript` to the `Process scripts` option (even this does not work in my express app).

But also in the online tool the `Minify JavaScript` checkbox does not change anything.

I don't know the possibilities of uglifyjs yet (a dependency of html-minifier) but with that name I would assume it should not only compress but also uglify the js code.

**Edit / Update**

I did some more research. I extracted the js code by regex match and just called uglify-js directly with the code. It had some problems with the handlebar fragments {{ }}. After removing them uglif-js works on the embedded js part of the template.

As I have set the option `ignoreCustomFragments: [/{{.*}}/g]` for the html-minifier I guess this should not be the problem?!

Here is the part that directly uses uglify-js

```
function minifyWithUglifyJs(orig: string): string {
    
    const re = /<script\b[^>]*>([\s\S]*?)<\/script>/gm;
    const match = re.exec(orig);
    if(match == null) {
        throw new Error(`Can't minify js in iframe template as found no match for js script!`);
    }

    const origJs = match[1] as string;
    console.log(origJs);
    const minifyResult = uglifyjs.minify(origJs);

    if(minifyResult.warnings != null) {
        minifyResult.warnings.forEach(logger.warn);
    }
    if(minifyResult.error) {
        throw new Error(`Can't minify the iframe template!`, {cause:minifyResult.error});
    } else {
        // replace orig js with minified js in code
        return orig.replace(origJs, minifyResult.code);
    }

}
```

Summing it up:

- **does anyone know what I do wrong with the http-minifier?**

Here is my attempt to minify in my node app (using html-minifier@4.0.0)

```
import htmlMinifier from 'html-minifier';

function minifyWithHtmlMinifier(orig: string):string {
    return htmlMinifier.minify(orig, {
        minifyJS: true,
        processScripts: ["text/javascript"],
        ignoreCustomFragments: [/{{.*}}/g]
    });
}
```

And here is some test code one can use [in the online tool](https://kangax.github.io/html-minifier/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Test ad</title>
    </head>
    <body onload="onLoad()">
        <div id="img-container" style="width:100%;height:100%">test text in page</div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            const longNameThatShouldBeUglified= 12;
            console.log("test");
            //{{another test}}
            function onLoad() {
                console.log("longNameThatShouldBeUglified (Not this time as it's a string) "+longNameThatShouldBeUglified);
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

Comment: Both, a tip to solve my problem with the html-minifier or recommendations to other solutions would be great.

Comment: I think you misunderstand. I try to get help fixing my configuration problem with html-minifier. With nearly 4,000,000 weekly downloads I don't think that the main feature of that library is broken. And please re-read: the online tool is just another front-end for me or other people to help me figure out what I do wrong. I have deleted the sentence about me being open for tips in other direction to ease your concerns that I could ask for "books, tools, software libraries, and more"...I do not

Comment: I have added the code.  But as calling the library is pretty easy, I think it is not that relevant. The online tool was meant as minimal reproducible example. Anyone can paste html/js in it and play around with the settings. If someone more aware than we would try, I am pretty sure s/he could use that tool to come up with a hint.

Comment: I have found a solution, please re-open the question so I can post an answer for people with a similar problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, that **[html-minifier does not give you any warnings when uglify-js throws any errors](https://github.com/kangax/html-minifier/issues/967#issuecomment-426645377)**. I thought I had misconfigured html-minifier becaue it did not minify.

After splitting my code to get only the content between the  tags and using uglify-js directly I saw the problems and could fix the to-be-minified code. As soon as it worked I switched back to using html-minifier and it worked.

I now use the following code where I **tell html-minifier to use uglify-js wrapped in some code to recognize any problems**.

```
function minifyWithHtmlMinifier(orig: string):string {
    
    return htmlMinifier.minify(orig, {

        // I have replaced the default minifyJS usage of the html-minifier
        // as this silently ignores any uglifyjs errors and just displays
        // the non-minified code. Has cost me half a day to figure out
        // that it was not a configuration problem  but problem with the 
        // to-be-minified-code.
        // By setting the call to uglifyjs myself I can catch the errors and
        // rethrow them, failing fast, as this is much better than recognizing
        // a not-minified code much later when I don't remember what I changed
        minifyJS: (text, _inline) => { 

            const minifyResult = uglifyjs.minify(text, {
                compress: {
                    drop_console: true  // remove all console log entries
                }
            });

            if(minifyResult.warnings != null) {
                minifyResult.warnings.forEach(logger.warn);
            }
            if(minifyResult.error) {
                // TODO maybe use terser. I think it supports
                // newer ES versions than uglifyjs
                throw new Error(`Can't minify the iframe template!`, {cause:minifyResult.error});
            } 
            
            return minifyResult.code;
            
        },
        minifyCSS: true,
        ignoreCustomFragments: [/{{.*}}/g], // handlebars fragments
        collapseBooleanAttributes: true,
        collapseInlineTagWhitespace: true,
        collapseWhitespace: true
    });
}
```

Important to note:
there is also [html-minifier-terser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-minifier-terser) that did not come up during my upfront research on what minifier to use with nodejs. Maybe it als does better reporting.